# Bootstrap 4 carousel-fade not working properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm having some issues with bootstrap's carousel, I have some images with different resolutions and ratios, and when I use the carousel-fade effect and two images with different ratios are next to each other the animation comes out janky.

I was wondering if there was a way to alleviate or solve this problem entirely

```
<div id="demo" class="carousel slide carousel-fade" data-ride="carousel" style="width: 800px;">
<ul class="carousel-indicators" id="car_ind">
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#demo" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ul>
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://images.corsidia.com/ckeditor/pictures/data/000/000/086/content/immagini-e-tabelle-html-00.jpg" alt="Los Angeles" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.urbannaturale.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/face-800-x-533px-photo-1498842812179-c81beecf902c.jpg" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://script.meteolive.it/admin/immaginiNotizie/SRC/__130766___taal1.jpg" alt="New York" />
    </div>
</div>
<a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#demo" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon"> </span>
</a>
<a class="carousel-control-next" href="#demo" data-slide="next">
    <span class="carousel-control-next-icon"> </span>
</a>
```

demo:
https://jsfiddle.net/02fxt9de/2/

Answer (score 0):

The main issue here is your image resolution
if they are different  it is obvious that the slide transition would appear janky . This can be solved by
setting resolution of image as equal

just replace this section in your code and try out

```html
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="https://images.corsidia.com/ckeditor/pictures/data/000/000/086/content/immagini-e-tabelle-html-00.jpg" class="carousel-img-size" alt="Los Angeles" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://www.urbannaturale.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/face-800-x-533px-photo-1498842812179-c81beecf902c.jpg" class="carousel-img-size" alt="Chicago" />
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="https://script.meteolive.it/admin/immaginiNotizie/SRC/__130766___taal1.jpg" class="carousel-img-size"alt="New York" />
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```css
.carousel-img-size {height:200px ; width:400px;}
```

change width and height as per your requirement. :)

Comment: ok but setting the height myself ruins the photo by streching it or scaling it down is there a way to maybe center it so that the image itself is not compromised?

Comment: changing height dosent affect the image , but the image will be skewed  if the width is changed and you can set a 
max-width: px ;     property so that image wont scale up beyond that limit

Comment: ok but we're back to the same problem, the animation come's out janky https://jsfiddle.net/fvwem0y3/3/